# ¿Como cargar imágenes desde una clase que esta dentro de un paquete dentro de un proyecto de maven?

Tags: java, netbeans, imagen, eclipse, maven

Buen día, estoy probando como colocar imágenes dentro de un proyecto de java hecho con Maven, y he encontrado que los archivos del código deben ir en *src/main/java* y las imágenes en *src/main/resources*.

Bueno al colocar los archivos de la siguiente manera

Clase: *src/main/java/Fondo.java*

imagen: *src/main/resources/Imagenes/fondo.png*

utilizando este código la imagen se inserta correctamente

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Fondo extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        
        ImageIcon fondo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Imagenes/fondo.png"));
        g2d.drawImage(fondo.getImage(),100,100, this);
        
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame ventana = new JFrame();
        Fondo panel = new Fondo();
        ventana.add(panel);
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ventana.setSize(700,700);
        ventana.setTitle("Mi Ventana");
        ventana.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}
```

**El problema sucede cuando pongo la clase dentro de un paquete**, de la siguiente manera:

Clase: *src/main/java/myPaquete/Fondo.java*

utilizando el mismo código, me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at myPaquete.Fondo.paint(Fondo.java:16)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:246)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1060)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:75)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:112)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:2002)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3928)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:876)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Lo he intentado tanto en NetBeans como en Eclipse.

Se que tal vez puede ser algo muy absurdo, pero he estado buscando y no encuentro una respuesta. Les agradecería si podrían ayudarme.

Gracias por sus respuestas :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no indicas una ruta absoluta ("/" al inicio de la ruta), *getResource()* usa una ruta relativa a la clase, por eso al mover la clase no encuentra la imagen.

Pon

```
 getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/fondo.png"))
```

O mueve la imagen a `src/main/resources/myPaquete/Imagenes`

Comment: oh, pues si jeje, gracias bro ya lo probé y si funciona

Answer (score -1):

Se que el problema problema de MAVEN con carpetas sigue hasta ahora (Uso Apache Netbeans 17 - Maven, pero este video da la solución de forma exácta:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_9qrcVq7T4
Ojala les sirva... a mi me ayudó un montón